# Using MySQL Aurora as source in Athena

Tags: amazon-athena, amazon-aurora

I would like to use a few Aurora(MySQL) tables as source when creating external tables on AWS Athena. Because, those tables are mutable and gets updated often. I see Hive and Presto support this by using `org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storagehandler.JdbcStorageHandler`. Is there an equivalent of any such feature in AWS Athena?

Comment: Correction, in Presto this is supported via a connector (https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/mysql.html).

Answer (score 3):

Amazon Athena is dedicated to running interactive ad hoc SQL queries against data on Amazon S3, the mentioned feature isn't supported yet.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/supported-format.html

You have two solutions in this situation:

1) You can use Glue or EMR service.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-connections.html

2) You can export the data from Aurora to S3 and then you can use Athena.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html

Comment: Could be worth updating this answer now that Athena can use JDBC compliant connectors - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-prebuilt-data-connectors-jdbc.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-prebuilt-data-connectors.html